# Search in a Claims Forms Auth (custom provider) WebApp

Tags: search, web-application-zones

Is there a way to enable search in a Wep App configured for Claims Form Authentication with a custom provider?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extend your web app and use a different zone for which you use the Forms AuthN (for instance the Intranet zone). Let the Default zone use NTLM AuthN and crawl that zone (always use the Default zone as your most secure zone, since it is the fallback one).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you "just" have to enable NTLM on the zone the crawler is using

Comment: I think we already tried that, but I'll check. Thanks